# При запуске функции в многопроцесорном режиме исполняется код который не является частью этой функции

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Доброго всем времени суток!
Работаю над программой которая построчно считывает списки из текстовых файлов и сравнивает с внесенным списком, для ускорения программы используется режим многопроцессорности, но при запуске функции в многопроцессорном режиме исолняется код который не является частью этой функции, то есть тот код с которого программа начинается, если же я запускаю этот код в обычном режиме (то есть просто вызываю функцию) то программа исполняется правильно.

Вот пример программы с такой же проблемой только без цикла (команда print('111111111111111111111')исполняется в мнгопроцессорном режиме, а должно в однопроцессорном )`

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

print('111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111')

def tr():
    t = 2
    return t

def read(z):
    x = 0
    t = tr()
    while x < 6:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        x = x + 1
        s = t * z
    print(s)
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(6)
    f = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
    res = pool.map_async(read, (f))
    print(res.get())
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

А если сам запуск функции произвожу в цикле то программа еще и ужасно тормозит ( в моем случае это цикл for для построчного считывания текстового файла но суть проблеммы от этого не меняется )

ПРИМЕР

```
while True:
    if __name__ == '__main__':

        pool = Pool(6)
        f = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
        res = pool.map_async(read, (f))
        print(res.get())
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Пожалуйста помогите разобратся в чем проблемма

Comment: `while True:` должен быть внутри блока `if __name__ == '__main__':`, а не наоборот. В принципе, чтобы код не выполнялся во вторичных процессах, он должен быть внутри этого блока.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, действительно поместив цикл while True во внутрь блока if __name__ == '__main__': программа перестала тормозить, но основную  проблемму это так и не решило( на каждом цикле исполняется команда print('11111111111111111') чего быть не должно да еще и в многопроцессорном режиме.

Comment: Цитирую свой же комментарий выше: "чтобы код не выполнялся во вторичных процессах, он должен быть внутри этого блока." Буквально, чтобы у вас `print('11111111111111111')` не выполнялся в каждом дочернем процессе, он должен быть внутри блока `if __name__ == '__main__':`. В принципе, можно для него сделать отдельный такой блок, но обычно все вносят в общий блок, возможно даже удобнее создать функцию main, которая будет вызываться из такого блока, и выполняться только в первоначальном процессе.

Comment: П.С. Возможно опытному программисту мои вопросы кажутся глупыми и ответы на них очевидными, но у меня есть оправдание я начал изучать язык python и писать программы вообще менее года назад, и спросить что то просто не у кого.

Comment: Огромное вам  спасибо insolor ! Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: В том что после вашей помощи у меня программа работала неправильно виноват я сам, я поместил блок программы if __name__ == '__main__': в функцию и вызывал ее соответсвенно из программы, поэтому команда  print('11111111111111111')  работала тоже в цикле.

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ ВАМ СПАСИБО insolor ! Я неделю голову ломал как это сделать!

Answer (score 0):

Правильно работающая программа!

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool



def tr():
    t = 2
    return t

def read(z):
    x = 0
    t = tr()
    while x < 6:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        x = x + 1
        s = t * z
    print(s)
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('1111111111111111111111111111111111111111')
    while True:
        pool = Pool(6)
        f = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
        res = pool.map_async(read, (f))
        print(res.get())
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО insolor !

Comment: pool = Pool(6) вынести перед while. Код будет работать в разы бысрее

Comment: Вынес, появилась ошибка 'ValueError: Pool not running'